# Compare Data from one worksheet to another and fill in the match

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, comparison, vlookup

I need some assistance with Excel 2010.  I would like to find a quick way to assign tickets, but not change previous ownership.

For example: I would like to compare my current list of unassigned tickets to my previous list and match the already assigned tech.

Current list of unassigned tickets that need assignments:

[image: Unassigned Tickets]

Previously assigned tickets to match unassigned ones and put in the previous assigned tech:

[image: Already Assigned Tickets]

I've experimented with VLOOKUP and MATCH functions but I'm just not doing something right.  I have my data on two worksheets in the same work book.
Assigned Tech is Column A and Ticket ID is Column C.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to match Ticket ID and return Assigned Tech, `VLOOKUP` isn't going to work with this data layout, because `VLOOKUP` will always look for a match in the left-most column of data. `MATCH` on its own won't work either, because by itself all it does is return the number of the row where it found a matching value.

You probably want to use the combination of `INDEX` and `MATCH`. I'll assume that your Assigned Tech is column A, and Ticket ID is Column B. Put this formula in column A:

`=INDEX($A$2:$A$100,MATCH($B2,Sheet1!$B$2:$B$100,0))`

Of course, replace names like Sheet1 with your actual worksheet name, and the range ?2:?100 with your actual data range. This will leave you with the tech names where there are names, and 0s where there are not.

Comment: Just to clarify, this is the formula that would go in A2 on the unassigned list, and Sheet1 in this case would be the one with the assigned techs.